# Code Splitting by using react router v4

Tags: webpack-2, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

In react router v3 i have implemented the code splitting using `System.import`, Now i want to upgrade my app to react-router-v4 but the problem is that i am unable to split my code.

> My `routes.js` file

```
function errorLoading(error) {
  throw new Error(`Dynamic page loading failed: ${error}`);
}

function loadRoute(cb) {
  return module => cb(null, module.default);
}

module.exports = {
  path: '/',
  indexRoute: {
    getComponent(location, cb) {
      System.import('../pages/IndexPage')
        .then(loadRoute(cb))
        .catch(errorLoading);
    }
  },
  childRoutes: [{
    path: 'notifications',
    indexRoute: {
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('../pages/NotificationPage')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      }
    },
  }]
};
```

and then i just imported the routes in my `index.js` file and rendered them to rootNode like

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer>
    <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
      <Router
        history={browserHistory}
        routes={routes}
      />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </AppContainer>,
  rootNode
);
```

Comment: Here’s an awesome video tutorial with code samples that you can follow to set up code splitting with React Router 4+ https://youtu.be/j8NJc60H294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it by simply adding routes like

```
<Route
  name="landing"
  path="/"
  getComponent={
    (_, cb) => import('./pages/LandingPage/LandingPage' /* webpackChunkName: 'landing' */)
      .then((module) => cb(null, module.default))
      .catch((error) => cb(error, null))
  }
</Route>
```

Never forget to use the `CommonsChunkPlugin` in your `webpack.js`

Comment: Is this possible with the new webpack v4 that deprecates the CommonsChunkPlugin ? Or better said, how to do it with the new version

Answer (score 2):

Check out [react-async-component](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-async-component). It has worked great for me on my [hapi-react-hot-loader-example](https://github.com/codeBelt/hapi-react-hot-loader-example)

```
import {asyncComponent} from 'react-async-component';

export default asyncComponent({
    name: 'AboutAsync',
    serverMode: 'resolve',
    resolve: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "About" */ './About'),
});
```

In the Router:

```
<Route
    path="/about"
    component={AboutAsync}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks codeBelt it worked and i also found a better solution without using any external package

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6 dynamic imports, you could go for [react-loadable](https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-loadable) and implement code-splitting this way:

```
export const AsyncComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "name" */ 'path/to/Component'),
  loading: () => null
})

// ...
<Route path='some/path' component={AsyncComponent} />
```